# SEO friendly urls to avoid duplicate content

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have nearly completed my .htaccess file now so that my urls all work properly. However i have a quick question:

I have a rewirte that looks like this :

```
    RewriteRule ^fishing/([^/]*)/?$ region.php?region=$1 [L]
```

This works in that if i type in fishing/fife/ it loads the region.php file. However what i didnt know nor expect was that if i type in region.php?region=fife then this also works.

I believe that this will give me duplicated content and my SEO rating will be effected. How do i make is so that if i type in region.php?region=fife that it automatically changes to fishing/fife/ ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't link to the Non-rewrite URL structure (i.e. region.php?region=fife) then there will be no way for webcrawlers to discover that URL and you won't get duplicate content.

If a human were to type in that URL and get the result, that is OK as far as SEO is concerned.

So just be sure to only use the pretty URL structure in your app.

Comment: Ok but here is one 'RewriteRule ^fishing/$ fishing.html [L]'
where fishing.html still works also. This the crawlers will be able to see? is that not right?

Comment: It's technically possible that a crawler could find that physical fishing.html page. If it is in a directory that has no index.html file and you allow directory browsing, then the crawler will be able to get a list of all of the physical files in that directory and go to them one by one. You could however use the robots.txt file to disallow the specific files or every file by extension if you need to. For example, if you will never use an extension in your url structure you could add `Disallow: /*.html$` to your robots.txt file to prevent any .html files from being crawled. Same for .php etc.

Comment: that sound like just the solution i need. I take it you just create a file named robot.txt and place it in the root of your website?

Comment: Yes exactly. If you sign up for http://www.google.com/webmasters/ they have a good robots.txt generator, or you can find similar ones online to help you.

Comment: Nice on. Thanks for all yout help

Answer (score 1):

The better solution to this is [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). This tells the search engines which URL is the one you want to show in the search results and that all other URLs that reach that page is a duplicate of it and to count it towards that [page's rankings (that includes incoming links).

You should *not* just hope the search engines don't find that other page. If they do that's duplicate content and obviously something you should be avoiding.